# Is $f$ defined by $f(x(t) ) = G(t , x(t))$ for all $x \in X$ differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, differential-geometry

Let $F: X \to Y$ be continuously differentiable function (in Ferechet sens) between Banach spaces $X = AC([0 , 1] , R^n)$, and $Y=L^{1} ([0,1] , R^n )$ with their usual norms.  Let $G: R \times R^n \to R^n$ be a continuously differentiable function.

My question is that is the function $f : X \to Y$ defined by 
$$ f(x(t) ) = G(t , x(t))  \quad \quad \text{for all }~ x: [0,1] \to R^n ~ \text{in}~ X $$
Continuously differentiable?

At first glance it seems $f$ is just a composition of two differentiable functions, but it is Not. Because $G$ is defined on the finite dimesion space $R \times R^n$ not $R \times Y$ !